# 301 redirects and url concatenation

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, concatenation, redirect

I need to do 301 redirects on 100+ urls so  was wondering if it's possible to use concatenation on the urls so that i don't have to type in every single one.

Sample urls would be similar to the following:

```
www.mysite.co.uk/ThisCategory/ThisSubCategory/reviews
www.mysite.co.uk/AnotherCategory/AnotherSubCategory/reviews
www.mysite.co.uk/YetAnotherCategory/YetAnotherSubCategory/reviews
```

I'm sure there is a way to just take any url beginning with www.mysite.co.uk/ and ending in /reviews but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following in `htaccess` at the root level:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/reviews/?$ http://new-web-page [R,L]
```

Comment: +1 this is correct and should work. Rule can be: `RewriteRule  /reviews/?$ http://new-web-page [R,L]` also.

Comment: @hjpotter92 Where is the use of 301 redirect in that though?

Comment: @StevePrice Change the `[R,L]` to `[R=301,L]` for 301 redirect status. Read more about rewrite flags on Apache docs here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_r