# Strange issue with .htaccess redirect rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, cpanel

Recently I changed my already established wordpress site URL structure from year & month based structure to postname structure. So, to redirect the old URLs to new URLs, I've added the below .htaccess rule to my sites root directory.

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$3
```

Everthing is working fine till to date. But the issue is that this rule is being applied to all the domains in my hosting account. I can't understand why this is happening.

Basically, my hosting company places the primary domain in the root directory (`/public_html/`) and places all the addon domains in their respective sub-folders (`/public_html/domain2/`).

I've added the rule to redirect my primary domain's URLs, But now this rule is effecting all the domains in my hosting account. Further more, when I check the redirects section in the cpanel I can see that the rule is being applied to all the domains. As a new member, I cannot add images, but use the link below to see the redirect rule in my cpanel.

[image]

Is there anyway I can modify it so that this rule only applies to one domain that I intended to? I would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25902776/1190388

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, try using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$3 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks, the URLs are redirecting correctly. Let me test it with other sites in my account.

Comment: My other sites are working fine too. I'm really glad this is working.